# Align stylus (pen) with touchscreen in rotated screen on Acer Travelmate Spin B1

Tags: touchpad, acer, touchscreen, xinput, stylus

I found a script to rotate my screen and the touchpad to the left and back to normal:

```
#!/bin/sh 

# Find the line in "xrandr -q --verbose" output that contains current screen orientation and "strip" out current orientation. 

rotation="$(xrandr -q --verbose | grep 'connected' | egrep -o  '\) (normal|left|inverted|right) \(' | egrep -o '(normal|left|inverted|right)')" 

# Using current screen orientation proceed to rotate screen and input tools. 

case "$rotation" in 
normal) 
#    -rotate to the left 
xrandr -o left 
xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axes Swap" 1
xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 1 0
xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 4 "Evdev Axis Inversion" 1 0
;;
left) 
#    -rotate to normal 
xrandr -o normal 
xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axes Swap" 0
xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 "ELAN Touchscreen" "Evdev Axis Inversion" 0 0
xinput set-prop --type=int --format=8 4 "Evdev Axis Inversion" 0 0
;; 
esac
```

Works fine. But what is not working is the stylus if the screen is rotated. I found a potential solution by change the Coordinate Transformation Matrix for the pen with:

```
xinput set-prop 'ELAN Touchscreen Pen Pen (0)' "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
```

This works fine, means if the screen is oriented normal and I run this command

```
xinput list-props 'ELAN Touchscreen Pen Pen (0)' | grep "Coordinate Transformation Matrix"
```

leads to

```
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

But it's reseted every time I use it in the script or if I run it if the screen is oriented in portrait mode, means if I run

```
xinput list-props 'ELAN Touchscreen Pen Pen (0)' | grep "Coordinate Transformation Matrix"
```

after I run the script or in "left" orientation I get

```
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
```

and the stylus is not working correct with this change orientation (up is left etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is an "reset" of the coordinate transformation matrix for the pen at the time the screen is rotated which overwrites the command. So I added a sleep time between conducting these commands and now it's working fine. 2 seconds has no impact since this time is needed until the screen is finally rotated

New script:

```
#!/bin/sh 

# Find the line in "xrandr -q --verbose" output that contains current screen orientation and "strip" out current orientation. 

rotation="$(xrandr -q --verbose | grep 'connected' | egrep -o  '\) (normal|left|inverted|right) \(' | egrep -o '(normal|left|inverted|right)')" 

# Using current screen orientation proceed to rotate screen and input tools. 

case "$rotation" in 
normal) 
#    -rotate to the left 
xrandr -o left 
xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
sleep 2
xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen Pen Pen (0)" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 0 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
;;
left) 
#    -rotate to normal 
xrandr -o normal 
xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
sleep 2
xinput set-prop "ELAN Touchscreen Pen Pen (0)" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
;; 
esac
```