# Pen is not rotated along with screen

Tags: wacom

Operating System: Ubuntu Budgie 18.10

Screen rotation works perfectly, including touch. However, the integrated digitizer does not rotate along, meaning that the axes and/or their orientation are mixed up. This happens on an Acer Spin 111 with a pen recognized by xinput as 04F3224A:00 04F3:255A Pen that presumably is manufactured by Elan. Unfortunately I have not found ways to determine any more information; neither lsusb nor lshw make it show up.

There seem to be some remedies available in form of scripts like the one given by
https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Acer/Spin1
However, that seems to risk doubling the action and thereby creating confusion. I think this should be taken care of the desktop environment directly.

As said, the rotation of screen and touch works just fine, so I would like to somehow add the necessary operations for the pen digitizer to that routine. I simply do not know where to start searching. Can anyone tell me what service reads the values of iio-sensor-proxy and launches the screen rotation? And maybe even how to influence the actions taken?

PS: tagging this question with "wacom" as it is not about touch although the ditigizer is of Elan brand.

Comment: Anything in this Q&A about Acer/Elan and pen rotation help you ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044910/align-stylus-pen-with-touchscreen-in-rotated-screen-on-acer-travelmate-spin-b1

Comment: I figured this would be a bit of a tumbleweed, but I've got a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 touchscreen and I'm having the same issue. I can rotate the display to vertical, but the touchscreen matrix remains as if it's horizontal, making it totally unusable. Would love to know if you've discovered anything other than the script you've linked.

Comment: Found another post related to this. With the info in this post I was able to make a little script that worked for me for rotating the display along with the digitizer inputs. Still working on making it respond to accelerometer events. https://askubuntu.com/a/405840/527080

Comment: The script I mentioned is [here](https://github.com/kael-shipman/ks-utils/blob/v1.x/src/usr/local/bin/ks-rotate-display)